# failed to put[create] (Invalid argument) OVS pop_mpls flow

Tags: linux, ubuntu, openflow, openvswitch

I face an issue in installing an OVS flow that pops mpls header off an incoming vlan tagged mpls packet. Following is the flow:

> ovs-ofctl add-flow br-int table=10,priority=20,mpls,mpls_label=100,actions=pop_mpls:0x0800,output:xx

The OF port to which the above packet is submitted belongs to a patch port. The above flow's packet counter increases but it's not output as directed in the action.

Furthermore, I receive [this](http://paste.openstack.org/show/606190/) error in syslog.

To add, I tried multiple combinations like stripping vlan, normal instead of output, removing mpls label match etc on the given flow.

Pls help me resolve this issue.

> > Linux compute-xxx 4.4.0-62-generic #83-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 18 14:10:15 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
> >
> > OVS 2.6.0, OF 1.3
> >
> > Xenial Xerxes
> >
> > VLAN based network

Comment: what are the modules of ovs installed?

Comment: @KarthikPrasad openvswitch-switch and openvswitch-common

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like OVS has put up a restriction on certain order of instructions and unfortunately, popping an mpls tag off an mpls+vlan packet falls under this.

So, we cannot pop an mpls tag off an mpls+vlan packet.

[This post in ovs mailing list speaks of the same problem](https://mail.openvswitch.org/pipermail/ovs-discuss/2016-April/040813.html)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same behavior described into this scenario using

> Open vSwitch 2.9.8
> OpenFlow15

I am guess that restriction on chain `pop_mpls` and `redirect` still exists.

There is a practical way to *bypass* this restriction? For examples:

- using `local` destination or `support interface` in order to fragment packet processing?
- another way?

Regards
Vincenzo